# Batch Script: Robocopy exclude files not working

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

Here is how I am creating and using the exclude file list:

```
:: Pull out parameters
set srcDir=%1 
set destDir=%2

:: Create exclude file
Set excludeFile=%temp%\exclude_list.txt

:: Populate exclude file
Echo.%srcDir%\web.config > %excludeFile%
Echo.%srcDir%\bin\*.* >> %excludeFile%
Echo.%srcDir%\custom\*.* >> %excludeFile%
Echo.%srcDir%\dataentry\custom\*.* >> %excludeFile%
Echo.%srcDir%\images\custom\*.* >> %excludeFile%

:: do a robust copy from source to dest
robocopy %srcDir% %destDir% /e /xf %excludeFile%
```

But none of this stuff is excluded in the final copy; am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /XD and /XF options expect a list of paths to exclude, not the name of a file containing paths to exclude.

```
:: Pull out parameters
set srcDir=%1
set destDir=%2

:: do a robust copy from source to dest
robocopy %srcDir% %destDir% /e /xd .\bin .\custom .\dataentry\custom .\images\custom /xf .\web.config
```

I believe you need to use the /JOB or /IF option if you want to specify parameters in another file, though I haven't used those options.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using xcopy? With it you can make an exclusion list, and it works very well.

Comment: I thought xcopy didn't understand wildcards? Regardless, I tried it just now and no change; excluded list was still ignored

Comment: xcopy is older than robocopy